# Javascript: Async/Await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

```
const account = await getName(id);
const domain = await getdomain(account);
```

Is there a way to combine these 2 using something like promise.props or promise.all

First resolved promise value is input to second.

Is piping possible for such an operation ?

Comment: What you have is correct. You cannot really use `promise.all` because the second call depends on the first.

Comment: I have a question to promise.all(), https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all
Why are the values which are logged in an array?

Comment: @Alex - post your own question, don't hijack someone elses question - the results are in an array because that's how Promise.all works

Comment: @Alex because `Promise.all` takes an array (or iterable) of promises, and produces an array of corresponding values. E.g, `[promise1, promise2, promise3]` produces `[resultOfPromise1, resultOfPromise2, resultOfPromise3]`

Comment: sorry thought that's not enough for a own question and it fits into this question.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to write

```
const accountPromise = getName(id);
const domainPromise = accountPromise.then(getdomain);
const [account, domain] = await Promise.all([accountPromise, domainPromise]);
```

but that achieves exactly the same as your original code, only in a much more complicated way. Choose the simple two sequential calls.